# iOS - UILocalNotification do not turn on screen

Tags: ios

Is it possible to have a notification displayed using a UILocalNotification appear in the lock screen when the screen is locked, but to not turn on the screen to display the notification?

The use case here is that I'd like to have the notifications seen when the user turns on their screen but the screen should not turn on when notifications are actually fired.

Comment: no you cant. apple doesnt allow it

Comment: Without body the user only notices the vibrating and the sound without turning on the screen.
But after turning it on, there will be no notification to read or interact.
So its mostly useless. (Maybe with a unique sound effect)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. You can not change the way `UILocalNotification` works. Either you don't use it or you accept its working way.

And the way `UILocalNotification` works is reasonable. At lease I think so.

Comment: Thanks - I guess the concern I have is that for something that displays a number of notifications the screen constantly turning on impacts battery life. It would be nice to see the list of notifications but not have the screen turn on each time.